# Google maps fullscreen offset pegman when dragging

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-street-view

I am having a problem with dragging the google maps pegman when it is fullscreen. The cursor position is offset from the pegman itself. The following image shows the cursor position as a black dot. I am not sure why this is only happening when the map is in fullscreen mode. The following is a related issue being tracked: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219154

[image: cursor position is black dot and pegman is offset from cursor]

Comment: I still think this is the [issue described here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219154). You can star the issue, comment on it, etc. This looks like quite a big issue so I would expect Google to fix this quite soon but... you never know...

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks, i thought I would follow your instructions and actually create my own post with more details.

Comment: Fair enough for the new question although it doesn't add much to the existing one we both seen. Still I would recommend you star the existing issue and possibly comment it with a link to this question as well.